# Can't access deployed report

Tags: reporting-services

I am working with SSRS on a windows 2008R2 installation and the report seems to have deployed but when I try to access the report I keep receiving, 'user' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and UAC restrictions have been addressed. I have granted the user full administrative permissions and have even tried running IE as administrator. I don't know what else to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user has access to the database/data source being used by the report, rather than the report itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this. Where would I do that? Would that be in the actual reporting service configuration?

Comment: From what I recall, there should be a web interface for the reporting services server.  Once there, find the report you deployed and attempt to locate settings for it.  There should also be an area dealing with shared data sources (if you're using those).  You may also go to the database itself and make sure that the user has permission there.  Either may work, and in my experience, user access is often due to the user not being allowed to access the database.